# Migrated SO question get an untagged tag

Tags: support, tags, migration

Questions on Stack Overflow with the [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) tag, that are migrated to Web Applications, will receive the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag upon migration:

[image]

Why is that? The tag on Web Applications is named: [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

Comment: There are no matching tags. That is, they differ by an "s" at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When migrating a question to another site the tags on the post must exist on the target site for the tag to remain.  If the tag doesn't exist, then the post is tagged with [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged).

For this particular question, the tag on Stack Overflow was [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) but the tag on the target site was [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) - there was no `s` on the SO tag.  Since the tag didn't match the post was untagged.

Answer (score 5):

Migration can only work with tags that match *exactly*. Stack Overflow uses `google-spreadsheet`, while Web Applications uses `google-spreadsheets`; the additional `s` is enough to make the difference here.

Without any matching tags, the question is given the special `untagged` tag; questions *must* have at least one tag.